# Get certain percentage data on each values of a column using spark java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to select 1 million records out of bigger data set. The data set has a column called "city". The 1 million records should contain 15% records from "city 1" , 30% records from "city 2", "55%" from "city 3". I could use limit as below to select. But it won't be a random selection.

```
dataset.filter(col("city").equals("city1")).limit(.15* 1 million)
```

I could use sample function. But I don't want to filter every city and sample it.

```
dataset.filter(col("city").equals("city1")).sample(false,percentage);
```

Is there a better way to get random sample percentage of data using spark java?

Comment: How many cities do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for [org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions.sampleBy()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameStatFunctions.html#sampleBy-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-long-)

```
dataset.stat().sampleBy("city", ImmutableMap.of("city1", 0.15, "city2", 0.3, "city3", 0.55)
```

Comment: Though it didn't give exact percentages, tweaking the seed value gives a closer result. Thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that you want the whole sample to be exactly 1M records. In that case you should calculate the sampling ratios as `ratio = count(city='city1') / (1M * 0.15)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a window, partitioned by city and ordered by a random column. You could then compute the rank and then only keep the first ranks.

Let's assume that you have a map `cityMap` that associates each city to the number of samples that you want to keep. You could either compute it from data, or know in advance what you desire.

I write the solution in scala to be sure it works, but translating to Java should be straightforward if you are familiar with the spark Java API. I tried to use java like syntax ;)

```scala
// creating the window
val win = Window.partitionBy("city").orderBy("random")

// defining a UDF that decides what records to sample
val isSampled = udf((r : Long, city : String) => r <= cityMap(city))

val sampledData = df
    .withColumn("random", rand())
    .withColumn("rank", rank().over(win))
    .where(isSampled(col("rank"), col("city")))
    .drop("rank", "random")
```